# get route and its children, given a route name

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm using `vue-router: 3.5.1` and I'm looking for a way to retrieve a route and its children, given a route name.

I know that with `vue-router: 4.x`, `router.getRoutes()` does this. While in `v3.x` the `getRoutes()` method doesn't.

I tried these ways :

> router.resolve({ name: myRouteName })

But it does not come with children routes.

> router.options.routes

But it comes in a hierarchy way and the route I'm looking for is not at the top level, so it doesn't find it.

> router.getRoutes()

But in v3.x, it doesn't come with children routes.

---

The only solution I have in mind is to find it with loops or recursion among `router.options.routes` but it can be dirty and not good in terms of performance maybe ?!

If someone has a different way to do it (while still using vue-router v3.x), I'm eager to learn.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The ` getRoutes()` does exist since v3.5. It gives you the whole routes' list flatted. You need to filter the returned array. https://v3.router.vuejs.org/api/#router-getroutes

Comment: @Mr.R Yes but the `getRoutes` from the `v3.5` doesn't include children for any route.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a patch for VueRouter v3.5.3

```
Index: \vue-router\dist\vue-router.esm.js
===================================================================
--- \vue-router\dist\vue-router.esm.js
+++ \vue-router\dist\vue-router.esm.js
@@ -156,8 +156,10 @@
 
   var route = {
     name: location.name || (record && record.name),
     meta: (record && record.meta) || {},
+    children: (record && record.children) || [],
+    parent: (record && record.parent) || {},
     path: location.path || '/',
     hash: location.hash || '',
     query: query,
     params: location.params || {},
@@ -1421,8 +1423,9 @@
         : route.alias
       : [],
     instances: {},
     enteredCbs: {},
+    children: route.children || [],
     name: name,
     parent: parent,
     matchAs: matchAs,
     redirect: route.redirect,
@@ -2358,9 +2361,9 @@
     if (this$1.pending !== route) {
       return abort(createNavigationCancelledError(current, route))
     }
     try {
-      hook(route, current, function (to) {
+      hook.call(this$1.router,route, current, function (to) { // provide Router instance as THIS for the Router guard; already bounded guard function won't be affected by CALL       
         if (to === false) {
           // next(false) -> abort navigation, ensure current URL
           this$1.ensureURL(true);
           abort(createNavigationAbortedError(current, route));
@@ -2531,9 +2534,9 @@
   match,
   key
 ) {
   return function routeEnterGuard (to, from, next) {
-    return guard(to, from, function (cb) {
+    return guard.call(this, to, from, function (cb) { // provide Router instance as THIS for the Router guard  
       if (typeof cb === 'function') {
         if (!match.enteredCbs[key]) {
           match.enteredCbs[key] = [];
         }
```

You can use [custompatch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/custompatch) to apply the patch in your project - like I do.